# how to correct this error in attached flutter document?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to get current signed in user data using future builder but this line {future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),}  throws an error{The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.}. And removing brackets at the end of currentUser gives another error {The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future'.}

````
//import 'dart:html';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import './message_bubble.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      //future:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
      //future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
      builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) {
        if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('chat')
                .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
              if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.documents;
              return ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: chatDocs.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
                  chatDocs[index]['text'],
                  chatDocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data.uid,
                ),
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```[error is present in line number 14 ,screenshots of error is also attached. I also tried by removing brackets at the end then another error arises(The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>'.)[\]\[1\]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x2JI.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to user FutureBuilder to get your User. `currentUser` is not a Future anymore but just a getter.

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Comment: I have tried above syntax before but it leads to other errors. please click on the link to view the screenshot of error

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hTMJHvQR7k2tL7Jj02F3Rdm8IRLUfQV_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What version of firebase_auth are you using ?

Comment: cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
 firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1

Comment: I rechecked the screenshot of the error. Your line is INSIDE the FutureBuilder constructor. Move it between line 11 and 12